# Handling exceptions in new process

Tags: .net, process, exception

I run a process from within my app. Sometimes the second process fails and throws exceptions, but I can't handle them in my first process and main app crashes, what shall I do.

I run second process as following :

```
try
{
Process proc = new Process();
...
proc.Start();
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
// never stops here even if proc fails
}
```

Comment: Are you bound to using a **Process** or could you schedule the work of your second process to a **Task**? If so, the code above should wait for the worker task to finish (Task.Wait) and could check Task.IsFaulted to learn if the task ended due to an unhandled exception.

Comment: Exceptions and their handling are per-process. You can't catch exceptions that have been thrown from a different process.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to switch from process execution to tasked based execution, you can try something along those lines:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ExceptionsInTasks
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {                    
                try
                {
                    var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork(i));
                    t.Wait();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception occured in run {0}: {1}", i, ex.InnerException.Message);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void DoWork(int i)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                throw new System.Exception("Faulty execution");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Successful execution in run " + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This results in the output below. Notice that the starting method has even details about the actual exception via `InnerException` property.

- Exception occured in run 0: Faulty execution
- Successful execution in run 1
- Exception occured in run 2: Faulty execution
- Successful execution in run 3